# I want to find a real number $x$ independent of $y$ and $x∈(y/a,y/b)$

Tags: real-analysis

I come across with the following situation when studying a problem related to discrete dynamics.

I have an interval of the form $(y/a,y/b)$ where $y>0$ is **fixed** and $a>b>0$

I want to find a real number $x$ independent of $y$ and $x∈(y/a,y/b)$

Comment: What do you mean by independent? (please answer by editing the question as this is quite a crucial point). Also, I suggest that you add some more context to your question.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Does not depend on the $y$.

Comment: I don't mean what "independent" means in English, I mean in your context. The only way I could see this make sense, the answer would be that you need to consider the intersection of all such intervals for all $y$, which is empty, hence there is no solution.

Comment: Can we assume $b>0$?

Comment: @J.G. Yes, we can.

Comment: As a native speaker of English, I can confirm that the OP's use of the word "independent" in this context is correct and unambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. If you choose an $x$, then I can choose a $y$ such that your $x$ fails to belong to the interval.